# Concurrent access to MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure to update a table with doing some calculations. What I am worrying about is if multiple users access this stored procedure concurrently, my calculations will be wrong. I don't know this is possible as I don't have much knowledge about MySQL. What I want to achieve is allow access to stored procedure only one user at a time. Is this situation handled by default or do I have to do some extra works.

Comment: if you are using a version of mysql that supports transactions and locking, you can prevent any problems like this

Comment: Can you explain this more? Thanks

Comment: explaining how transactions and locking work is way beyond the scope of my comments.  In brief, if you start a transaction and lock rows everyone else will automatically wait until you are done and commit your changes before they access those rows.

Comment: Please explain how multiple people accessing the same stored procedure concurrently would lead to problems. What is the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to control concurrent access to a stored procedure in MySQL.  You'll need to control concurrent access to the appropriate row of the table instead. This isn't hard.

Here's what you do:

First, use InnoDB or some other transaction-capable access method. MyISAM won't work.

Second, identify some particular row in some table around which the operation revolves. For example, you might be updating a row with `id` number 17 in a table called 'calc' as part of your computation.  You'll `SELECT` this row `FOR UPDATE`, and that will prevent other

Third, write your stored procedure code like this:

```
 /* make sure you'll clean up correctly if something goes wrong */
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;

 /* begin a transaction */
 START TRANSACTION;
 ...

 /* lock the row you want to update, or to use to control concurrency */
 SELECT id FROM calc WHERE id=17 FOR UPDATE;
 ...

 /* do your calculations and updates */
 ...

 /* when you're done, commit the transaction */
 COMMIT;
```

The cool thing about this is that each concurrent access to the particular row will delay the completion of the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` until the preceding one finishes its `COMMIT`.  If you have concurrent clients updating different rows they will run concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is seems works for me. Can I know that it is possible to lock more than one row at a time. As a example if I use  SELECT * FROM calc WHERE id < 10 FOR UPDATE;  Will this lock all rows which id < 10 ?

Comment: Yes, you can lock lots of rows.  But it might not be a good idea. Before you start doing that from many concurrent processes, read about deadlocks and how to avoid them.